# How to Generate Scripts For All Triggers and tables in Database Using pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-9.2, pgadmin-4

I'd like to generate an SQL script that contains the SQL to create all of the triggers and tables that exist in our database. I have already tried the method where you right-click the table, select `script -> create Scripts`. While this does create a SQL script for the table, it does not create a script for the trigger functions of that table. What should I do?

I also tried:

```
SELECT tgrelid::regclass
     , tgname
     , pg_get_triggerdef(oid)
     , pg_get_functiondef(tgfoid)
FROM   pg_trigger
WHERE  tgrelid = 'public.tablename'::regclass;
```

but it is not useful because it creates a CSV file.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Did you already consider `pg_dump` (with perhaps `-s` option if you don't want data)? [9.6 docs here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pg-dumpall.html)

Answer (score 1):

`pg_dump` is probably the best option here, as it is the export tool that comes bundled with Postgres and is designed to do (more or less) exactly this. The only catch with the requirement you've specified is that it specifically asks for certain object types (which I am assuming here is a strict requirement).

`pg_dump` does have the `-s (--schema-only)` flag, which will dump all of the `create` statements, for all objects (not just tables and triggers). So I guess there are 2 options:

1. **dump the whole thing and then sort it out afterwards.** I don't really like this idea, because you have to go through the trouble of scripting around the start/end of all kinds of different SQL statements in order to pick out just the stuff that needs to be removed. Too messy.
2. **write a script that wraps `pg_dump` and and pre-selects only the triggers and tables**. Have the script use `psql` to query the Postgres system tables to fetch the names of all `table` and `trigger` objects. Then feed that list into `pg_dump` to export each object on an individual basis.

Option 2 sounds a lot easier, but also slower since I think the triggers might need to be done one-by-one (the tables can be done in bulk using the `-t (--table=TABLE)`option to `pg_dump`). But since it's only dumping schema objects and no data, it probably isn't going to make a big difference.

You can pick out the triggers like this:

```bash
pg_dump -s -Fc | pg_restore --trigger='my_trigger'
```

And that could be wrapped up in a script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

my_db='db_name'

triggers=($(psql --dbname="${my_db}" -A -R ', ' -t \
            -c 'select tgname from pg_trigger'))

for trigger in "${triggers[@]}"; do
  pg_dump -s -Fc | pg_restore --trigger="$trigger"
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patiently response, As I am new in SQL I have some problems. Would you please exactly describe for me if I have a table which name is :"A" and it has two triggers which names are "B and C", and the table A is related to another table with foreign keys. how should I write the above code?

Comment: In the case you described the same approach would still work. First you would run `pg_dump` on the table: `pg_dump -d 'my_db' -h 'db_hostname' -U 'db_user' -T 'A'` and then use the same concept as the script to dump the triggers: `pg_dump -s -Fc | pg_restore --trigger='B'` and `pg_dump -s -Fc | pg_restore --trigger='C'`

Comment: `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` are command line tools that come with Postgres. I don't think you can run them with pgAdmin. You need to run them in a terminal.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try that